# Augmented Reallity - how to render texture after replacing teapot object in ios

Tags: ios, opengl-es, augmented-reality, autocad, vuforia

I am ios developer, developing AR on iPhone. Customizing vuforia SDK for replacing teapot object.
Until now able to replace Teapot with another 3d .obj model. I have used furniture model But how can I get the texture of that furniture (.png) file Like TextureTeapotBlue.png in Sample code file.
    I have done lots of thing like :

1. Use 3d max : render to texture property to bake object to its png texture file. But results inproper.
2. Convert .mtl file to .h file but it doesn't consume the png/tga files.
3. Lastly I have found link : https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/qcar-api/texture-problem-imagetargets-when-changing-model

The link contain the solution found as
*"I found the problem,it was so tricky...     In fact, softwares like blender, 3DSMax, do NOT use the same coordinate system (U,V for the texture mapping) as OpenGL ES does...
OpenGL ES use an mirror image of the one blender use. So I have to transform the texture by applying a horizontal mirror transformation.---By Allan"*

Here not understood "a horizontal mirror transformation" and to generate it.

Give me the correct direction to render texture image properly on my 3d object.

Comment: Give me ans if you have. No need of your negative remark.

Answer (score 0):

I think "horizontal mirror transformation" is just a fancy way of saying that the texture coordinates need to be swapped.  So, for example, if the texture coordinates for a quad are:

```
GLfloat TexCoords[] =
{
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f
};
```

Then, just swap the vertical values like this to mirror the image:

```
GLfloat MirroredTexCoords[] =
{
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

Comment: Thanks For replay ClayMontgomery.. I don't have problem related 3d model, object. The problem while sending rendering texture. And I think there might be some ratio apply with texture and 3d object size.